# TableView dont work in swift help me pls

Tags: json, swift, parsing, tableview

The following code works properly but "for" block does not work
so "TableView" into the data is not added.

How can I solve this problem?

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    var NumberOfRows = 0
    var BaslikArray = [String]()
    var GonderenArray = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        parseJSON()

    }
    func parseJSON(){

        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://10.10.5.1/mjson.php");
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST";
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        let postString = "istek=pmliste&eposta=abc@abc.com&sifre=70c5fb2837e3edf992674a06fc876920&salt=sMb&tt=1";

        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            let readableJSON = JSON(data: data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)
            self.NumberOfRows = readableJSON["pm"].count

            for var i = 0; i < self.NumberOfRows; i++ {
              let aa = readableJSON["pm"][i]["baslik"].string!
               self.BaslikArray.append(aa)
                NSLog("\(readableJSON["pm"][i]["baslik"].string!)")
            }

        }

        task.resume()

    }



      override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection     sesction: Int) -> Int {
           return NumberOfRows
        }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell" , forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        if BaslikArray.count != 0 { 
        cell.textLabel?.text = BaslikArray[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `reloadData` on the table view after the data is done loading. I.E., after the for loop is finished.

Another thing you can do to make your code better is to remove the `NumberOfRows` property. Just use `BaslikArray.count` wherever you need to know how many rows there are.

Comment: self.BaslikArray.append(aa) This code does not work here .. "task" outside working when I tried